# How to close a Bootstrap modal that contains a form when the form is submitted?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I've a form into a bootstrap modal, I want to close the modal when the user click the submit button. Looks like that :

```js
export class AddPartModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id:number;
  closeResult: string;
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private graphService:GraphService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
      }
    }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    //some code
  }

}
```

```html
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">New element</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f);" #f="ngForm"><!--here if I add 'modal.dismiss('Cross click')', it dosen't submit or it dosen't close the modal (depend if I add it before or after the 'onSubmit()')-->
      <!--some form content-->
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="f.invalid">Create</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<button (click)="open(content)" style="background-color: transparent; height: 100%; width:100%; border: none;"><h4 style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">+ add part +</h4></button>
```

And so I don't know how to close the modal, is there a way to close it in the `onSubmit` function?

I've tried to use `modal.dimiss` into the `onSubmit` function but it doesn't work, I probably didn't understood how bootstrap modal works, if you have any advice I'll be happy to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dismiss function or the dismissAll function to close the modal.

```
onsubmit() {
  ...
  this.modalService.dismissAll();
  //or
  this.modalService.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: .dismiss() does not exist within the NgbModal service. It supports open, dismissAll, and hasOpenModals. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModal

Answer (score 0):

See if this works... Pass in #content instead of the ngForm into onSubmit. Call dismiss on content within your fn.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(content);" #f="ngForm">
```

Within your HTML template, you've named your modal 'content' via template reference. It'll be passed along to your function...

```
onSubmit(modal: NgbModal) { 
  modal.dismiss(); // <-- modal will be referring to the above template reference. It's type is NgbModal, which has all the properties, including 'dismiss' and 'open'. 
}
```

If you need validations for the form, then I would pass in the ngForm, in this case, 'f'. I've only found it useful to check whether or not the form has been submitted. Other than that, I use the form group I've defined within my component.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, could you give me code details please ?